# Firebase Database overwrites previous value with setValue()

Tags: java, android, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I have a Database in Firebase.

This code is in onCreate():

```
DatabaseReference mDatabaseRefUser =FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
```

This code is in another method that gets called onClick:

```
mDatabaseRefUser.child("Chat").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid())
            .child(userID).child(uploadID).child("Messages").push().setValue(new ChatMessage(addMessageEditText.getText().toString(),
            mAuth.getCurrentUser().getEmail()));

mDatabaseRefUser.child("Chat").child(userID)
            .child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child(uploadID).child("Messages").push().setValue(new ChatMessage(addMessageEditText.getText().toString(),
            userEmail));
```

What im trying to do is to add a new value without deleting the previous/existing value everytime the method gets called.

For the moment everytime I click and start the method, the previous/existing value gets removed and the new one gets added. But I want neither to be deleted. I want this the new value to be added aswell. I have tried with getRef and push() but my data still gets overwritten. What am I doing wrong here?

This is my JSON 1st time I call the method:

```
"Users" : {
"Chat" : {
  "Xta3jwm4yLQWaJBypMBFt2esiOr2" : {
    "xfqAFlRpbUZRlZb76svN5FUtbU93" : {
      "-LCvIA_9L1Y9rjkm96Aj" : {
        "Messages" : {
      "-LCvqDidnNqQ8ALZhDud" : {
        "messageText" : "Very good",
        "messageTime" : 1526791230552,
        "messageUser" : "mama@mama.com"
      }
    },
    "chatAgainstUserEmail" : "mama2@mama.com",
    "chatAgainstUserID" : "xfqAFlRpbUZRlZb76svN5FUtbU93",
    "uploadID" : "-LCvIA_9L1Y9rjkm96Aj",
    "userEmail" : "mama@mama.com",
    "userID" : "Xta3jwm4yLQWaJBypMBFt2esiOr2"
  }
}

},
  "xfqAFlRpbUZRlZb76svN5FUtbU93" : {
"Xta3jwm4yLQWaJBypMBFt2esiOr2" : {
  "-LCvIA_9L1Y9rjkm96Aj" : {
    "Messages" : {
      "-LCvqDigI8ZwHDYuPhw9" : {
        "messageText" : "Very good",
        "messageTime" : 1526791230555,
        "messageUser" : "mama2@mama.com"
      }
    },
    "chatAgainstUserEmail" : "mama@mama.com",
    "chatAgainstUserID" : "Xta3jwm4yLQWaJBypMBFt2esiOr2",
    "uploadID" : "-LCvIA_9L1Y9rjkm96Aj",
    "userEmail" : "mama2@mama.com",
    "userID" : "xfqAFlRpbUZRlZb76svN5FUtbU93"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is my JSON when I call it for the 2nd time

```
"Users" : {
"Chat" : {
  "Xta3jwm4yLQWaJBypMBFt2esiOr2" : {
    "xfqAFlRpbUZRlZb76svN5FUtbU93" : {
      "-LCvIA_9L1Y9rjkm96Aj" : {
        "Messages" : {
      "-LCvr0zoHOPxsKOVJzeu" : {
        "messageText" : "Very good 2nd call",
        "messageTime" : 1526791440547,
        "messageUser" : "mama@mama.com"
      }
        },
    "chatAgainstUserEmail" : "mama2@mama.com",
    "chatAgainstUserID" : "xfqAFlRpbUZRlZb76svN5FUtbU93",
    "uploadID" : "-LCvIA_9L1Y9rjkm96Aj",
    "userEmail" : "mama@mama.com",
    "userID" : "Xta3jwm4yLQWaJBypMBFt2esiOr2"
  }
}
  },
  "xfqAFlRpbUZRlZb76svN5FUtbU93" : {
"Xta3jwm4yLQWaJBypMBFt2esiOr2" : {
  "-LCvIA_9L1Y9rjkm96Aj" : {
    "Messages" : {
      "-LCvr0zrh8wQ2WurUezs" : {
        "messageText" : "Very good 2nd call",
        "messageTime" : 1526791440550,
        "messageUser" : "mama2@mama.com"
      }
    },
    "chatAgainstUserEmail" : "mama@mama.com",
    "chatAgainstUserID" : "Xta3jwm4yLQWaJBypMBFt2esiOr2",
    "uploadID" : "-LCvIA_9L1Y9rjkm96Aj",
    "userEmail" : "mama2@mama.com",
    "userID" : "xfqAFlRpbUZRlZb76svN5FUtbU93"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have also tried with `getRef().push()`, but that didn't work either. I have also tried without .`getRef()` and without `.push()`, didnt work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My only solution to this issue was to make a new Database,

I added this:

```
mDatabaseRefUser.child("Chatting").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid())
                .child(userID).child(uploadID).child("Messages").push().setValue(new ChatMessage(addMessageEditText.getText().toString(),
                mAuth.getCurrentUser().getEmail()));

        mDatabaseRefUser.child("Chatting").child(userID)
                .child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child(uploadID).child("Messages").push().setValue(new ChatMessage(addMessageEditText.getText().toString(),
                userEmail));
```

and removed the old one

Answer (score 0):

To update a value instead of overriding it, you should use [updateChildren()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#update_specific_fields) method.

You are overriding it because every node in a Firebase database is a `Map` and in the case of `Map`, it replaces the old value with the new one.

Comment: I have tried this aswell it still overwrites. It wasn't me who downvoted btw

Comment: What is the difference between those 2 json files?

Comment: Difference is that when I add the new value "very good 2nd call", the old value "very good" gets deleted

Comment: I understand. One more question. What is `Xta3jwm4yLQWaJBypMBFt2esiOr2` and what is `xfqAFlRpbUZRlZb76svN5FUtbU93`?

Comment: those 2 are, UID of the users chatting with each other. Yes I solved it by below answer

Answer (score 0):

To update data you should go for such kind of code instead of using `child.setValue()` as its name suggests it will directly replace old values with new values. But If you want to change a specific value then you should go for something as below. Give it a try mate!

```
HashMap<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("yourKey", your value);   
yourDatabaseChildReference.updateChildren(params);
```

Comment: using updateChildren(hasmap), it gave me same result as adding push()